# Wordpress Database Error establishing a database connection

Tags: database, wordpress

I updated my PHP from 5.4 to 7 and after that my wordpress website cannot connect to the database.

When I put the line `define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);` within the wp-config.php and go to address: `http://www.address.com/wp-admin/maint/repair.php` I still have the same error

> Error establishing a database connection

When I connect to my wp-admin, I got the following:

[image]

Finally I checked my credential on my database within wp-config.php, they are correct but when I do a `mysql> show databases;` I got the following:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Answer (score 0):

please edit wp_config file 
use this code:

```
define('WP_ALLOW_REPATR',true);
```

Comment: or fllow this link https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-error-establishing-a-database-connection-in-wordpress/

Comment: I did and still same issue. It works perfectly and suddenly cannot connect anymore. I do a testconnection.php and it cannot connect, I checked my config file, no problem there. I then use my 2-days old backup and website works perfectly, I check testconnection works perfectly, config file exactly the same. Then after few days it crash again...